# Ruby on Rails: How to save a model that is dependant on two others?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails. I have set up a basic User / Post Model which allows a User to create Posts. I am trying to create Comments for the Posts, which will also relate a Comment to the User who created it.

I have set up the relationships so that a User has many Posts and Comments, a Post belongs to a User and has many Comments, and a Comment belongs to both a Post and a User.

My problem comes in when trying to save a Comment. In my Comments controller:

```
def create
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(params[:comment])
end
```

This does not work and says nothing about which Post the Comment belongs to. I am also displaying the 'Add Comment' form on the Show Posts page in order to create a Comment Wall below the Post, but my form still just says

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
```

And does not relate the comment to the Post in the Posts controller under Show.

I realize there is probably a straightforward answer but could not find any resources that explained my specific issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you're primarily adding the comment to a specific post.  So start there:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])  # <== this may be just `id`
  @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
  @comment.user = current_user

  if @comment.save
    # ... do things
  else
    # ..  render error
  end
end
```

For this to work you're going to need your route to be nested:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

And your `form_for` will need to indicate the nested route:

```
<%= form_for [@post, @comment] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the right thing in CommentsController#create

```
@comment = current_user.comments.build(params[:comment])
```

The part that you're missing is include the post_id in your params[:comment]. That should be no problem because you always know the post you're commenting on, the one that you're showing. So add the following inside your `form_for @comment`

```
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, @post.id %>
```

I am assuming this is in your show post view, and you have set @post in your PostController#show

Comment: nzifnab's approach is just as valid, and the one I would probably choose if I am starting from scratch. I suggested my option instead because it requires no changes to your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
  @comment.user = current_user
  if @comment.save ...
```